# Why is this line giving me a c2120 error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
} while (mf_bingo(c) != 5);
```

this is the line that I keep getting the error on.  I tried putting a void before the mf_bingo(c) and taking out the (c)

edit:
here is the full loop

```
do

    {
        char yesNo;
        int c, d;
        if (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Player 1 how many numbers are on your card" << endl;
            cin >> c;
            mf_bingo(c);
        }

        else if (yesNo == 'n' || yesNo == 'N')
        {
            cout << "Sorry player 1" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Player 2 do you see this number on your card." << endl;
        cin >> yesNo;
        if (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Player 2 how many numbers are on your card" << endl;
            cin >> c;
            mf_bingo(c);
        }

        else if (yesNo == 'n' || yesNo == 'N')
        {
            cout << "Sorry player 2" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Press 1 to continue generating random numbers." << endl;
        cin >> d;
        mf_numbers(d);
    } while (mf_bingo(c) != 5);
```

and here is mf_numbers

```
void mf_numbers(int d)
{
    int xRan;
    srand(time(0));
    xRan = rand() % 50 + 1;
    cout << xRan << endl;

}
```

here is mf_bingo

```
void mf_bingo(int c)
{
    if (c == 0)
        cout << "You need to match get 5 more matching numbers to win." << endl;
    else if (c == 1)
    {
        cout << "You only need 4 more matching numbers to win" << endl;
    }
    else if (c == 2)
    {
        cout << "You only need 3 more numbers to win" << endl;
    }
    else if (c == 3)
    {
        cout << "You only need 2 more numbers to win" << endl;
    }
    else if (c == 4)
    {
        cout << "You only need 1 more number to win" << endl;
    }
    else if (c == 5)
    {
        cout << "You win!!!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is its function signature?

Comment: what error is c2120?

Comment: We need to see the mf_bingo function prototype.

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yte3yy7h.aspx

Comment: Can you post a bigger code snippet the error might not actually be on that line, sometimes MSVC isn't entirely accurate with the line numbers. That error typically occurs if you do something like 'void int x;' See the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yte3yy7h.aspx

Comment: Looks like you're either using `void` with another type, or `mf_bingo` doesn't return an `int`.

Comment: It sounds like `mf_bingo` returns `void` which you cannot compare to `5`. `mf_bingo` will need to return a type that can be compared to an `int`

Comment: Error [c2120](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yte3yy7h.aspx) is about mixing void in declarations with other types.  This is not the case here.  Please show the function propotype, as well as the code around this error.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the declaration of void `mf_bingo()`.  You have to make this function returning an `int`.

You can reproduce this problem with the following code:

```
void mf_bingo(int c) {  // void doesn't return anything
}

int main() {
    do { } while(mf_bingo(c) != 5);
}
```

The error [C2120](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yte3yy7h.aspx) explains that, as the function returns `void`, i.e. nothing, you can't compare it with an integer.   Normally, intellisence should already highlight mf_bingo as potential error, with a more accurate description.

You can easily correct this:

```
int mf_bingo(int c) {  // here we return something 
    ...   // same logic as before 
    return c; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Compiler Error C2120](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yte3yy7h.aspx) means that you are using `void` type where you should be using another type (in your case: `int`).

You need to change:

```
void mf_bingo(int c)
```

to:

```
int mf_bingo(int c)
```

And change the body of the function appropriately, so that it would return an `int`, making the line you mentioned: `} while (mf_bingo(c) != 5);` work as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 4):

`mf_bingo` returns a `void` which you cannot compare to anything. You will need `mf_bingo` to return a type that can be compared (in your example, it needs to be comparable to `5`). You can probably just have it return `true` or `false` based on whether the player wins or not:

```
bool mf_bingo(int c)
{
    if (c == 0)
    {
        cout << ...
        // no win:
        return false;
    }
    etc...
    else if (c == 5)
    {
        cout << "you win!";
        return true;
    }
    // no match:
    return false;
}
```

Comment: well you don't need to return false each time. just return false at the end of the method. and return true under else if c == 5

Answer (score 2):

`mf_bingo` has return type void (i.e. it returns nothing), you are treating it in your while loop as if it returns an integral value.

To fix it you could change the signature of the function to `int mf_bingo(int c)` and it could just return `c`. As `mf_bingo` doesn't actually alter `c` it seems a bit pointless to do this.

So you already have the value `c` that you want to check for in your loop termination condition.

You could just do it like

```
do
{
   // other code

   // just print stuff
   mf_bingo(c);

} while(c < 5);
```

**Also Note**

You should also face another issue in that you define `c` inside the `do while` loop. This may also not compile and probably not function correctly.

e.g.

```
int main()
{
    do
    {
        int c = 1;
        c++;        
    }
    while (c < 5);

    return 0;
}
```

If this compiles (it shouldn't), you'd have an infinite loop as `c` will never reach 5. Moving `c` outside the loop. Its all ok.

```
int main()
{
    int c = 1;
    do
    {
        c++;        
    }
    while (c < 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're right. but his loop is actually an infinite loop. c is never incremented.

Comment: True, but I was only trying to solve the immediate issue of the compilation error.